# async await не приостанавливает синхронную функцию node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Есть request, который запрашивает со стороннего ресурса айдишки пользователей, затем по этому айди надо достать группы, которые администрирует этот пользователь, очень не хочется устраивать callback hell, решил прибегнуть к async/await, в итоге пропал на 2 дня.

Есть этот код:

```js
  request(urlRender.accessUrl(code), async(function(error, response, body) {

   var tokenJSON = JSON.parse(body);
   var token = tokenJSON['access_token'];
   var userId = tokenJSON['user_id'];

   console.log("tokenJSON", tokenJSON);

   var groupsId = await(group.getGroups(userId, token));

   console.log("groupsId", groupsId);
      // ....
     }));
```

А это код groups.getGroups:

```js
module.exports.getGroups = function(userId, token) {
  var groups = [];
  var user = "user_id=" + userId;
  request(urlRender.reqVk("groups.get", user, token, "&filter=admin"), function(error, response, body) {
    var groupJSON = JSON.parse(body);
    // console.log("groups", groupJSON['response']['items']);
    var arr = groupJSON['response']['items'];
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      groups[i] = arr[i];
      console.log("iteration ", groups[i]);
    }
    return groups;
  });
};
```

При этом в терминале я вижу вот что:

```
tokenJSON { access_token: 'censored',
  expires_in: 0,
  user_id: censored }
groupsId undefined
iteration  censored1
iteration  censored2
iteration  censored3
iteration  censored4
iteration  censored5
iteration  censored6
```

Следовательно, groupsId выводится в консоль до наполнения. Скажите мне пожалуйста, где моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка - в том, что `async await` это не какая-то магия и приостановить произвольную асинхронную функцию оно не может. Оператор `await` ожидает справа обещание (promise, промис) - и чтобы он заработал, вам надо его предоставить.

Начать можно с обертки над функцией `request`:

```
function requestAsync(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error)
                reject(error);
            else
                resolve(body);
        });
    });
}
```

Теперь `requestAsync` возвращает обещание - а значит, ее можно вызывать справа от оператора `await`:

```
module.exports.getGroups = async function(userId, token) {
    var groups = [];
    var user = "user_id=" + userId;
    var body = await requestAsync(urlRender.reqVk("groups.get", user, token, "&filter=admin"));
    // ...
}
```

Ну а теперь, когда `getGroups` тоже стала асинхронной - ее уже тоже можно использовать справа от `await`.

PS если request - ваша собственная функция, то вместо написания обертки над ней лучше исправить ее, чтобы она тоже возвращала обещание.

Comment: Не, request - это npm модуль. Спасибо, огромное, ща попробуем